# Footnote with right parenthesis

Tags: formatting, captions, footnotes

I want to put a closing round parenthesis next to a footnote. I use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, since the footnote is part of a caption.

```
  \begin{center} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{...} 
    \caption[...]{...\protect\footnotemark}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\vspace{15pt}

\footnotetext{...}
```

How can I configure a command for using a footnote with parenthesis?

Comment: It's bad practice to footnote text of captions. For one thing, at least: if the figure floats on another page, the footnote will be in the wrong place. Add the text of the footnote to the caption.

Comment: @egreg, I am writing my bachelor thesis and the quoting regulations require a footnote with closing paranthesis for the captions of figures. I tried to avoid `\footnotemark`and `\footnotetext` but found no other solution.

Comment: Where should the closing parenthesis be positioned? After the footnote mark in the caption, e.g. "1)", or at the end of the footnote text?

Comment: After the footnote mark in the caption and at the beginning of the footnote text.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23601/footnote-number-in-braces/23612#23612) answer shows how to add left and right braces to the footnote marks in text and footer. It should be easily adaptable to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, this almost solves my problem! Is there a way to make a new command so that I can differentiate between a standard footnote and a quoting-footnote? Something like `\footnotemarkquoting`? I don't want the closing paranthesis to be put at every footnote.

Comment: Just to be sure: But the two footnote types should use the same counter?

Comment: If that is possible, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution -- I cloned the original definitions of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` and added a closing brace at the appropriate location. (If one wanted to use the optional arguments of `\footnotemark`/`footenotetext`, more "cloned"  definitions would be needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\quotingfootnotemark{%
  \@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark
  {\stepcounter{footnote}%
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote)}%
  \@footnotemark}}
\def\quotingfootnotetext{%
  \@ifnextchar [\@xfootnotenext
  {\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn)}%
  \@footnotetext}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[A figure]{A figure\quotingfootnotemark}
\end{figure}

\quotingfootnotetext{A quoting footnote.}

Some text.\footnote{A standard footnote.}

Some text.\footnotemark

\footnotetext{A standard footnote produced with \texttt{\textbackslash
    footnotemark} and \texttt{\textbackslash footnotetext}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mirco: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote my question as soon as you have enough reputation to do so (15). ;-)