# Footnote marker followed by closing right parenthesis, not superscripted

Tags: footnotes

I’m trying to reproduce some old typography somewhat faithfully — a German article from 1925.  It marks all footnotes using a number followed by a right parenthesis, similar to what’s described in the question [Footnote with right parenthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26853/footnote-with-right-parenthesis) and produced by [lockstep’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26856/1635), except that only the number is superscripted — the parenthesis is at normal size and alignment, in both the body text and footer.

- In body text: [image]
- In footer:
  [image]

I’ve tried adapting that earlier answer, but it looks like this will require going deeper into the footnote mechanism, and I can’t quite figure it out.  The body-text part is easy, as shown in the following MWE (done inline, but obviously could be put into a macro); getting it in the footer as well is what I’m stuck on.  I include hyperref since it’s the one package I’m using which interacts with the footnote mechanism.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english,main=german]{babel}

\begin{document}
Etwas etwas etwas\footnote{Etwas mehr}) noch etwas.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried; your MWE just uses the regular `\footnote`.

Comment: @PeterWilson: I’ve tried redefining `\footnotemark` following the [linked answer by lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26856/1635), but everything inside `\footnotemark` is superscripted.  So my MWE using plain `\footnote` really is the closest I’ve been able to get — it demonstrates the exact desired result in the body text (very straightforwardly), and for the footer, I haven’t figured out how to add anything placed with the footnote marker (not the footnote text) but not superscripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
% fnprob.tex  SE 666624

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}})}
    
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{A footnote}
\end{document}
```