# Footnote mark in regular or other font styles

Tags: formatting, footnotes

Within my text, I use `\footnote` to place text. This places a small superscripted number within the text as well as a number at the bottom of the page followed by the data within the footnote.

- How can I change the appearance the number mark which appears within the text, so that it follows a normal text style just like the other text around it (not superscripted)?
- How can I change the appearance of the number mark which appears at the bottom of the page to the left of the footnote? Can this be changed to match the numbers in a list style?
- Can these settings change the appearance of all marks within the document uniformly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can redefine `\@makefnmark` and `\@makefntext` to achieve the behavior you describe. We look at the original definition with `\makeatletter\show\@makefntext\makeatother` and produce

```
> \@makefntext=\long macro:
#1->\parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark }#1.
l.6 \makeatletter\show\@makefntext
```

and with `\makeatletter\show\@makefnmark\makeatother` we produce

```
> \@makefnmark=macro:
->\hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \@thefnmark }}.
l.7 \makeatletter\show\@makefnmark
```

In the latter case, we get rid of the `\@textsuperscript` to address question one. I am not sure, I understand 'number in a list' correctly, but I added a period after the number in `\@makefntext` to address question two. If you like other changes, you can add them in the same way.

This affects all footnotes in the whole document and should, therefore, be consistent for all footnotes. You can look at the `footmisc` or the `scrextend` package to get more options for footnote issues. You will also find some more in [question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo) and [question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23601/footnote-number-in-braces-parentheses).

[image: footnote numbering example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2in]{geometry}

\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefnmark{%
\hbox {{\normalfont \@thefnmark }}}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark.}#1}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\show\@makefntext\makeatother
Word \footnote{This is a word.} Word \footnote{This is also a word.}
\end{document}
```