# Footnote mark in non-superscript with ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context, context-mkii

Usually a footnote has a mark within the text (which is superscript) and a mark near the footnote text at the bottom of the document (which is also superscript). How can I change the mark within the text (but not the mark at the bottom of the document), such that it is not superscript (with ConTeXt MKII)?

- I have found similar solutions for this in LaTeX (see [How to set superscript footnote mark in the text body but normalsized in the foot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19844/how-to-set-superscript-footnote-mark-in-the-text-body-but-normalsized-in-the-foo) and [Footnote mark in regular or other font styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34663/footnote-mark-in-regular-or-other-font-styles)), but I have found no way to adjust these solutions for use in ConTeXt.
- ConTeXt has `\setupfootnotes` ([ConTeXt wiki: Reference/en/setupfootnotes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Reference/en/setupfootnotes)), which seems to offer a lot of customization of the footnotes, but after much experimenting, I have not found any way to modify the mark such that it is no longer superscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also remember that in MkIV it's not

```
\setupfootnotes[textstyle=normal, textcommand=\tf]
```

but

```
\setupnotation[footnote][textstyle=normal, textcommand=\tf]
```

I'm using the following now to achieve non-superscript numbers

```
\setupnotation[footnote][way=bypage,numbercommand=\tf]
```

Answer (score 5):

Better make your own minimal example (if you have done much experimenting, you must have something to show). This does what you appear to be looking for:

```
\setupfootnotes[textstyle=normal,
        textcommand=\tf]

\starttext

This is a\footnote{Footnote}.

\stoptext
```