# Inserting space after the number in footnotes

Tags: footnotes

Text of Footnotes are very close to their numbers. How can I make 2mm space after all footnote numbers (or 2mm before every footnote text)?

```
\documentclass[draft,12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
X\footnote{x}

Y\footnote{y}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question. I guess you are trying to adjust the distance between the number of the footnote and the footnote text (and *not* the regular text).

If you want to do so, try this:

```
\documentclass[draft,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}
\begin{document}
X\footnote{x}

Y\footnote{y}
\end{document}
```

Normal spacing:

[image]

Increased spacing:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Here is on possible solution that redefines the `\footnote` command. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution using a package, but this works. The amount of space can be adjusted by changing the value inside of `\hspace{}`; it is currently using 2mm as specified.

**Output:**
before: [image], after:[image].

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[draft,12pt,a4paper]{article}
% ADD THESE LINES TO YOUR PREAMBLE %
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
\oldfootnote{\hspace{2mm}#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
X\footnote{x}

Y\footnote{y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Including package footmisc with Beamer makes footnotes disappear. Don't know why. But this solution works.

Answer (score 8):

This suggestion is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34667/4771).

```
\documentclass[draft,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark}\hskip2mm\relax#1}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
X\footnote{x}

Y\footnote{y}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the superscripted footnotemarks, so I use the following settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fnBreite}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
  \protect\footnotesize\upshape%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\columnwidth}\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\fnBreite}%
  \makebox[\fnBreite][l]{\@thefnmark.\phantom{}}%
  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\everypar{\hspace*{1em}}\hspace*{-1em}\upshape#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a new\footnote{displays here} footnote
\end{document}
```

[image]