# biblatex footcite no line breaks

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking, footnotes

I'm writing a document that must fit within a predefined page limit, and therefore I must save as much space as I can. I'm using the `footcite` command, and my preamble contains

`\usepackage[style=verbose,babel=hyphen,backend=bibtex,block=ragged,firstinits=true,isbn=false,isbn=false=false,eprint=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}`

and this produces something like
[image]
The question is: is there a way to prevent line breaks after each reference? Perhaps putting all references into a single column format, without line breaks?

An suggestion that would save some space is more than welcome!

Comment: You could try `\footcites` to gather some of the citations together, in the cases in which that makes sense in your document.

Comment: I know, but this would break the logic of the citations. I need each reference to be identified by a unique number, and replacing the line break before each new number with, for instance, a wide space

Comment: The problem here is that each `footcite` will produce a footnote, so the issue is less one of citation, then of how the footnotes are handled in the document. As far as I see, at least. I get your point though, but I might as well recall that the verbose style does not depend on the numbering of the footnotes to be an unambiguous reference system, so I think you might reconsider using `footcites` of even `footcite` with multiple entries if you don't need prenote/postnote, if that's not a requirement that is impinged on you from somewhere else than the citation style itself.

Comment: I'd like to better understand your last point, since, in general, I don't need post-notes or pre-notes. The references are indicated by a superscript, which refers to a footnote. If I put multiple references into a single `footcite` I get a single superscript and single footnote (as far as I know), and so there is no way for the reader to understand to which exact part of the text the citation is referring to. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you want a simple `para` style for the footnotes? This would of course effect all footnotes.

Comment: You understand correctly, a `footcite` with multiple keys would generate a single superscript.

Comment: Note that your questions seems to be more about footnotes and their layout than about the content of the footnotes as produced by `biblatex`. So it is also important to see what document class you use and how it produces footnotes in general. A full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) could give us a good starting point.

Comment: What you can do to further save space depends on what you can change in your document. If you are submitting to a journal it is unlikely you are allowed to change a lot, I'd even doubt that you are allowed to change the footnotes in the way you want. But if you are free to change details that might be fine. Maybe you can even change the citation style radically to something `numeric`. Depending on how often you cite certain works and on whether you have a separate bibliography at all that might save some space.

Answer (score 3):

footcite are footnotes. So you should use a para-footnote style. As you didn't show a complete example it is not possible to say if it works with your class/document.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,babel=hyphen,backend=bibtex,block=ragged,firstinits=true,
           isbn=false,isbn=false=false,eprint=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
bllb \footcite{doody}, bööb \footcite{herrmann}, blblb \footcite{doody}
\newpage

bllb \footcite{doody}, bööb \footcite{herrmann}, blblb \footcite{doody}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks a lot !! :)
Do you know how I can set the white space before and after each number?

Comment: Before is \footglue. Behind can only by changed by redefying \@makefntext.

Comment: Cool !! Taking inspiration from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34667/140906 I redefined `\@makefntext` as

`\makeatletter% \long\def\@makefntext#1{% \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss \@makefnmark}#1}%\makeatother`

and `\setlength{\footglue}{0pt}` allowed me to get the right spacing