# How to have both symbolic footnote (counters reset per page) and numeric footnote (numbering never resets) threads on top of each other?

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I would like two footnote threads:

- one that uses traditional American footnote symbols (such as *†‡§¶‖) and whose counter is reset every page
- one that uses continuous (Arabic numeral) numbering throughout the entire document.

I also like my footnote markers to be set into the margin, with a small separating space.

Let's start with a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\footmarkstyle{\textsuperscript{#1\ }} % to have an additional space after footnote marks (not easily possible with the footmisc package)
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-1sp} \setlength{\footmarksep}{0em} % same effect as \usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} % continuous numbering of footnotes across chapters

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is dummy text.\footnote{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 1, as it currently is.}

\chapter{Document body}
This is dummy text.\footnote{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 2, as it currently is.}
This is dummy text.\footnote{I want this footnote to be introduced by the symbol \(^{*}\) and be placed above the previous footnote, even though it comes later in the text.}

\end{document}
```

Basically, the last footnote should be symbolic and should appear above the numerical ones; in general a stack of symbolic ones should appear above a stack of numeric ones on any given page, *without* additional vertical separation.

(Bonus if there is an easy way for me to specify the symbol sequence.)

*There is [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57445/numbering-a-group-of-footnotes-differently), but this one is different in coverage and trickier.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The package `bigfoot` allows easily for this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B} % If we omitted this declaration (and used \footnote instead), that'd place the standard footnotes _above_ the \footnoteA ones.

\footmarkstyle{\textsuperscript{#1\ }} % to have an additional space after footnote marks (not easily possible with the footmisc package)
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{-1sp} \setlength{\footmarksep}{0em} % same effect as \usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} % continuous numbering of footnotes across chapters

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 1, as it currently is.}

\chapter{Document body}
This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 2, as it currently is.}
This is dummy text.\footnoteA{I want this footnote to be introduced by the symbol \(^{*}\) and be placed above the previous footnote, even though it comes later in the text.}

\newpage

This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 3, as it currently is.}
This is dummy text.\footnoteA{I want this footnote to be introduced by the symbol \(^{*}\) and be placed above the previous footnote, even though it comes later in the text.}

\end{document}
```

The order in which the footnotes appear on the page is based on their declarations in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks! is there an easy way of disabling the vertical space? (`bigfoot`'s documentation itself seems to play around with this but doesn't tell me how to do it, I think.)

Comment: @user14996 The separation is the same as it's used between the text and the first block of footnotes; if you zero it, then the footnotes will run into the text block.

Comment: It would be great if the package author added this as a refinement.

Comment: (This isn't about your solution, which is good.) I noticed that `bigfoot` together with `\raggedbottom` and "here"-placement (`H` table placement with the `float` package) in some complex document I have leads to plenty of overfull `\vbox`es (in my case: tables that don't fit onto the page but fail to trigger page breaks). Is this a known problem?

Comment: @user14996 The problem is most probably, due to `[H]` placements which give too little flexibility to the page.

Comment: I find that, outside of the TeX community, "`[H]` table placement with `\raggedbottom` text (though not necessarily `\raggedbottom` table placement, for a good reason)" is very common. Also, the copyediting guides that I know of tend to not have an opinion on table placement. I'm not disagreeing with you, just emphasizing the importance and popularity of `[H]`.

Comment: Yeah, I get too many `Overfull \vbox ...`-messages (and plenty of tables that are placed in a way that pages overflow vertically). Also it doesn't seem to play well with `hyperref`. (Using `manyfoot` and `perpage` has exactly the same effect/result.) Writing this down partly for documentation/reference.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: The space between the two footnote blocks can be changed with `\skip\footinsB=0pt`.