# Mixing symbols and numbers as footnote markers

Tags: footnotes

I have several numbered footnotes in a text, but some of them I would like to see them as symbols. I tried with the next command

```
\footnote[10]{this is a footnote}
```

and it works, it changes the next number by 10, but if intead of 10 I use `\dag` it doesnot work, or if I use `\dagger` it writes 8825. Any idea?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate) question?  [How to have both symbolic footnote (counters reset per page) and numeric footnote (numbering never resets) threads on top of each other?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74655/2693). Be aware that the `bigfoot` package is sparsely documented, but adapts the syntax for `manyfoot`, so that its documentation will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, probably the package `bigfoot` resolve the problem, but I was looking for something easier. Actually, hopefully, I found the next solution. If I define the next line in the preambule

```
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnotetext[#1]{#2}\footnotemark[#1]\endgroup}
```

it resolves the problem. Thanks.