# Footnote citation superscript in square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes, superscripts

I'm using `biblatex` to build my citations and my bibliography for a math paper. However, I have certain portions like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am trying to say "as d tends towards 1" but with the superscript citation it seems like I'm saying "as d tends towards 1 to the power of 17". To prevent misinterpretation, I have decided to enclose each superscript in square brackets. How can I do this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[british, 11pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}


This is a test script\footcite{BrinPage1998}. As $d \longrightarrow                         
1$\footcite{BrinPage1998}.
```

Here is the `Biblio.bib`:

```
@article{BrinPage1998,
author={Brin, Sergey and Page, Lawrence},
title={The Anatomy of a Large-scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine},
journaltitle={Computer Networks and ISDN Systems},
volume={30},
issue={1-7},
pages={107--117},
date={1998-04-01},
url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0169-7552(98)00110-X},
urldate={2017-04-02},
publisher={Elsevier Science Publishers B. V.},
address={Amsterdam, The Netherlands, The Netherlands},
}
```

Comment: I assume you want this for all footnotes, not just those involving a citation. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23601/35864

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick for me. Is there any way to mark this question as a duplicate? @moewe

Comment: Brilliant. Done.