# Citation numbers in normal script and in parentheses

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm currently writing a paper and my supervisor has given me specific citation rules but no template.

One of these rules is:

1. Citation numbers are in superscript in the text but at the bottom of the page in normal script and in parentheses.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, 12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Language specification

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Required to output umlauts in a PDF
\usepackage{pslatex}

% bibliography and citation management


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}  
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @Book{zimmermann1973judeneid,
        Title                    = {Die Entwicklung des Judeneids},
        Author                   = {Volker Zimmermann},
        Publisher                = {Peter Lang},
        Year                     = {1973},
        Series                   = {Europäische Hochschulschriften. Reihe I. Deutsche Literatur und Germanistik},
        number                   = {56},

        Location                 = {Frankfurt am Main},
        Subtitle                 = {Untersuchungen und Texte zur rechtlichen und sozialen Stellung der Juden im Mittelalter}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

    Some text\footcite{zimmermann1973judeneid}  

    \printbibliography[title={Literatur}]

\end{document}
```

It now looks like

[image: It now looks like]

It should look like

[image: It should look like]

Thank you very much for any help and suggestions on how to manage the problems!

Comment: this is an edited version of the original question, this is why I let the numbering of the problem in, even when there is only 1. since the posted answer tackles 1. The previous question is separated into two threads.

Comment: How do citations interact with normal footnotes? What happens if you cite the same work twice (on the same page, on different pages)?

Comment: I should also mention that on this site it is usually *strongly* preferred to ask about only one thing per question. Since you already separated out four sub-questions it would have been nicer to ask them separately, that way people with similar questions can benefit from the answers more easily and you don't risk scaring away people who know only answers to some of your sub-questions. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864

Comment: @moewe This is indeed a good question, since the \footnote{} command should behave the same as stated in my problem 1. They are counted like the \footcite{}-commands with superscript numbers on the bottomof the page. With the verbose-style I get the short-title when reciting an item which is fine (same on every page). I didn't know about the custom to only ask one question at a time, I'm sorry for that. Should I split the thread? Thanks for your fast answers.

Comment: So they are simply normal footnotes? That would make things *a lot* easier.

Comment: How would it be easier? I'm afraid I can't follow.

Comment: Well, easier than the alternative which would require citation footnotes and normal footnotes to be handled differently. (That should be possible, but is quite messy, in my experience, especially when references to the same work on the same page are only supposed to appear once etc. etc.)

Comment: It would be possible to only use \footnote{}, with the simple workaround \footnote{\cite{bibitem}} instead of \footcite{bibitem}. I don't think there are major downsides with this workaround. So just modifying the \footnote{}-command would be sufficient for 1. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this, the tricky part seems to put the number in normalscript on the bottom of the page, since I only found answers for putting the numbers in parenthesis like [link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23601/footnote-number-in-braces-parentheses)

Comment: I will split my question, hopefully this evening if I have the time. The current question will transform to problem 1. which is the topic @moewe discussed. I hope this will be proper etiquette.

Comment: Well, since `\footcite` internally just uses footnote, issue 1 would indeed ideally be solved by just redefining the footnote output. What about separating that issue from the rest of this question in a new question. It should  be fairly straightforward for people who know about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments I will only tackle issue 1 for now. Since this issue is only about footnotes and not really about `biblatex` at all, the MWE can be simplified quite a bit.

In the standard classes the command `\@makefntext` can be redefined to modify the output of footnotes. Its standard definition in `article.cls` is

```
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
```

where `\@makefnmark` typesets the exact same footnote mark that `\footnote{...}` produces in the text and is defined as

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

Since the footnote mark in the text should remain as is, we don't redefine `\@makefnmark` directly, instead we use `\@thefnmark` and redefine the marker in `\@makefntext`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@2.4em{\hss(\normalfont\@thefnmark)} #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill % just to skip some space in the example
Some text\autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnote with number in parentheses.]

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, I was thinking long ago about a similar layout, but where the footnote is abridged as much as possible – only first author, abbreviated journal names, no pages, no doi, and so on, but the references still list the full citation with all the omitted stuff. I found no good way of doing so, even if there are some pointers like `maxnames`, see http://www.khirevich.com/latex/bibliography/.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Producing a reduced reference in the footnote is possible, you just need to do some work to tell `biblatex` exactly what you would like to see in the footnote. Depending on what *exactly* one has in mind for the footnote setup (by which I mean: How do reference footnotes interact with normal footnotes? What happens if an entry is cited twice on the same page or multiple times on multiple, different pages? In case references can appear out of order on a page, do they need to be 'sorted' in the footnotes?), that would be the tricky bit.

Comment: My _actual_ idea was to use sidenotes from tufteLaTex (or, basically, `marginpar`'s), so indexing should not be an issue. I'd need to dig out biblatex the next time I am adventurous, because for now bibtex + natbib worked like a charm for anything (except that).